# Replace NA with if-else in DataFrame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to replace NA in a column with "A", "B", or "C" based on values from another column by using if-else in DataFrame.

I tried:

```
df$grade[is.na(df$grade)] <- ifelse(df$score >= 28, "C", ifelse(df$score < 14, "A", "B"))
```

But got an error:

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Then, I tried another code:

```
df1 <- replace(is.na(df$grade), ifelse(df$score >= 28, "C", ifelse(df$score < 14, "A", "B")))
```

But also got an error:

```
Error in replace(is.na(df$grade), ifelse(df$score >= 28, "C", : argument "values" is missing, with no default
```

Can anyone please explain to me why I got these error and how to fix them?

Truly appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to subset `score` as well.

```
inds <- is.na(df$grade)
df$grade[inds] <- with(df,ifelse(score[inds] >= 28, "C", ifelse(score[inds] < 14, "A", "B")))
```

---

Probably, using `case_when` would make it cleaner.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(grade = case_when(!is.na(grade) ~ grade, 
                           score >= 28 ~ "C",
                           score < 14, "A", 
                           TRUE ~ "B"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Ronak Truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fcase` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, grade := fcase(is.na(grade), grade,
                          score >= 28, 'C',
                          score < 14, 'A',
                            'B')]
```